# How to detect which button was pressed

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know which button was pressed in a list of many buttons. For example, if the 2nd button was pressed, then the code detects that the button the second way down was pressed and returns something like `[1]`. However, I don't know how to do this. When I searched, jQuery was involved, but I am not using jQuery. The code is as follows:

```js
var table = document.getElementById("Table");
function CreateRow() {
  var CoreButton = document.createElement("Button");
  var ButtonText = document.createTextNode("Add");
  CoreButton.appendChild(ButtonText);
  document.body.appendChild(CoreButton);
  var NewRow = table.insertRow(-1);
  var NewName = NewRow.insertCell(-1);
  var AddRow = NewRow.insertCell(-1);
  AddRow.id = "AddRow";
  AddRow.className = "AddRow";
  AddRow.appendChild(CoreButton);
}
```

```html
<html>
<table id = "Table">
<button onclick="CreateRow()">Add Button</button>
</table>
```

I tried using EventListner, by adding EventListner to every button created, but that didn't distinguish between individual buttons. Note that each button has an id of `AddRow` and a class of `AddRow`. 
If anyone could help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add something like a data attribute to each button starting from 1 and set up an eventListener like this

This will set an eventListener on the document and return if the click target did not match an element with the .AddRow class.
If it matches access the data attribute per e.target.dataset.

```
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if(!e.target.matches('.AddRow')) return;
    console.log(e.target.dataset.id);
});
```

Button example

```
<button class="AddRow" data-id="1"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var table = document.getElementById("Table");
function CreateRow(obj) {
  var row = parseInt(obj.getAttribute('data-row'));
  var CoreButton = document.createElement("Button");
  CoreButton.classList.add('btn');
  CoreButton.setAttribute('data-row', row+1);
  var ButtonText = document.createTextNode("Add");
  CoreButton.appendChild(ButtonText);
  CoreButton.addEventListener('click',function(){CreateRow(CoreButton)}, false);
  document.body.appendChild(CoreButton);
  var NewRow = table.insertRow(-1);
  var NewName = NewRow.insertCell(-1);
  var AddRow = NewRow.insertCell(-1);
  AddRow.id = "AddRow";
  AddRow.className = "AddRow";
}
```

```html
<table id = "Table">
<button data-row='1' onclick="CreateRow(this)">Add Button</button>
</table>
```

I would use above code, in the row variable I would get the row number and then use my own logic to manipulate the further actions.